# Whats wrong in given caml query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml, date-time

I am trying to get the data based on some datetime string using CAML query.

Here is my CAML query:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Le>
                    <FieldRef Name='StartDateTime'/>
                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>2017-03-23T05:20:00.000Z</Value>
                </Le>
                <Ge>
                    <FieldRef Name='EndDateTime'/>
                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>2017-03-23T05:20:00.000Z</Value>
                </Ge>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

When I am passing the value of date-time in ISO string it gives me error "**500 (Internal Server Error)**"

If I pass date without converting to ISO string it gives no result.

I am using SharePoint Online, my current timezone in regional setting is set to India.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for my list. You just check the internal name of the fields `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime` and date format mention in the value section in query `2017-03-23T12:00:00Z`

I think you mention `Le instead of Lt(less than)/Leq(less than or equal) and Ge instead of Gt(greater than)/Geq(greater than or equal)` and `.` in this `2017-03-23T05:20:00.000Z`

see below my example.

```
<View>  
    <Query> 
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Lt>
                    <FieldRef Name='StartDateTime' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>2017-03-23T12:00:00Z</Value>
                </Lt>
                <Gt>
                    <FieldRef Name='EndDateTime' />
                    <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>2017-03-23T12:00:00Z</Value>
                </Gt>
            </And>
        </Where> 
    </Query> 
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='StartDateTime' />
        <FieldRef Name='EndDateTime' />
    </ViewFields> 
</View>
```

Answer (score 4):

The operators "Le" & "Ge" are not valid. It needs to either "Lt"/"Gt" (Less than/Greater than) OR "Leq"/"Geq" (Less than or Equal/Greater than or equal").

Also, it may be that, one would use "Geq"/"Gt" with Start Date and "Leq"/"Lt" with End date.